# Show a text if the post has written by author user role in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I search a PHP code what is show a certain text or html code on the post page when the post author is an author. (not admin or editor)

When the post author is an admin or editor then show nothing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this code on your post page

```
<?php if( current_user_can('author') ) {  ?>
    // echo your content here
<?php } ?>
```

I think It will help you